# /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4 367c76_amd64.deb

Tags: boot, command-line, system-installation, upgrade, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I'm getting this error while trying to upgrade to Pop!_OS.

```
After this operation, 399 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 224343 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~43
67c76_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pop-gnome-initial-setup (3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-s
etup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4367c76_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/vendor.conf', which is 
also in package gnome-initial-setup 3.36.2-0ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pop-gnome-initial-setup_3.36.1~1612193315~20.04~4
367c76_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.